# Saving pictures using ffmpeg from my webcam with both strftime and %%d

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam

I tried saving image from my webcam, since strftime in ffmpeg 4.2.2 does not provide microseconds, to avoid overwriting the image in the same seconds, I plan to use both strftime and sequence number.

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f image2 "%04d.jpg"
```

gives 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f image2 -strftime 1 "%F_%H-%M-%S.jpg"
```

gives 2020-07-25_01-02-03.jpg, 2020-07-25_01-02-04.jpg ...

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f image2 "%F_%H-%M-%S_%%04d.jpg"
```

gives 2020-07-25_01-02-03_%04d.jpg, 2020-07-25_01-02-04_%04d.jpg ...

I would expect the %%04d will be replaced with numbers, but it does not. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I belive the command you entered, look like this:

`ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f image2 "$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%%d").jpg"`

According to [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) `date` command can give you a nanoseconds (not microseconds). Use following command as a possible solution:

`ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f image2 "$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%S_%N").jpg`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Inject the date by shell command will cause all filename saved using the same date that the command first start. What I am going to achieve is naming the filename at the moment of saving.

Comment: I didn't get the question right. FFMpeg can use `strftime` c++ function for output filename. But strftime function can't show microseconsds or similair value (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/). All I can afford is to use frame number (`"%04d.jpg"`). It seems you can`t combine `strftime 1` and standart filename pattern.